# Visual Studio 2013 Unit Test error: Could not load Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

For some reason the unit tests from a test project in VS 2013 (w/Update 3) doesn't show up.

````
Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\
COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. Unspecified error (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))```
````

When checking the folder, the file is there.

My Chutzpah tests in another project in the same solution shows up. Couldn't find much info on this error when searching. Anyone had similar issues or know how to resolve this?

Comment: That is odd. If you think its connected to the contents of that project could you file an issue at https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah and include a project that repros this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case  , I have noticed in the Test Project's app.config file, that more than one assemblyIdentity where enclosed as part of  tag, which should not be.

**Improper configuration**

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
<assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureEventSource" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Proper Configuration**

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="WindowsAzureEventSource" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Holy crap you just saved my life. I was beating my head against a wall with this issue, thank you so much.

Comment: yeah. for me it happened to be the improper auto-merge issue across branches. Good to see at least the post helped some one.

Comment: oh man after 2 days of debugging this was the problem. Thank you for posting this. ARRGHHHHHHHHHH

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trial and error, I noticed there was a app.config file in the test project for some reason. Removing this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Related answer:  I was trying to be clever and use the XML directive thingey to comment out large sections of app.config that included other comments.  Don't use `<?... ?>` directives in app.config.